# Can I filter listview in DRF with different URL patterns?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I currently have `/items/` point to the listview of all `Item` objects and a detailview also. I have done this using `ViewSets`.

Is it possible for me to get `/items/category/` to display list of items in that category?

Is it possible for me to get `/items/category/subcategory/` to display list of items in that subcategory?

I want to do the above using ViewSets and Routers only.

Answer (score 1):

You can add extra functionality like this to viewset using [`@list_route`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing):

```
class ItemViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Item.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ItemSerializer

    @list_route()
    def category(self, request):
        category_items = Item.objects.filter(category_id=1) # for e.g.
        serializer = self.get_serializer(category_items, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    @list_route(url_path='category/subcategory')
    def category(self, request):
        category_items = Item.objects.filter(category_id=1, subcategory_id=2) # for e.g.
        serializer = self.get_serializer(category_items, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

New fuctions will be available on followinbg url `/items/category/` and `/items/category/subcategory/`.